# How to calculate count of each value in MySQL JSON array?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, mysql-8.0

I have a `MySQL` table with the following definition:

```
mysql> desc person;
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field  | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| id     | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| name   | text    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| fruits | json    | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+--------+---------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

The table has some sample data as follows:

```
mysql> select * from person;
+----+------+----------------------------------+
| id | name | fruits                           |
+----+------+----------------------------------+
|  1 | Tom  | ["apple", "orange"]              |
|  2 | John | ["apple", "mango"]               |
|  3 | Tony | ["apple", "mango", "strawberry"] |
+----+------+----------------------------------+
```

How can I calculate the total number of occurrences for each fruit? For example:

```
+------------+-------+
| fruit      | count |    
+------------+-------+
| apple      | 3     |
| orange     | 1     |
| mango      | 2     | 
| strawberry | 1     |
+------------+-------+
```

Some research shows that the `JSON_LENGTH` function can be used but I cannot find an example similar to my scenario.

Comment: which mysql version are you using`?

Comment: @nbk MySQL version 8.0.18

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `JSON_EXTRACT()` function to extract each value ("apple", "mango", "strawberry" and "orange") of all three components of the arrays, and then then apply `UNION ALL` to combine all such queries:

```
SELECT comp, count(*)
FROM
(
 SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(fruit, '$[0]') as comp FROM person UNION ALL
 SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(fruit, '$[1]') as comp FROM person UNION ALL
 SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(fruit, '$[2]') as comp FROM person 
) q
WHERE comp is not null
GROUP BY comp
```

Indeed If your DB's version is 8, then you can also use `JSON_TABLE()` function :

```
SELECT j.fruit, count(*)
  FROM person p
  JOIN JSON_TABLE(
                 p.fruits,
                '$[*]' columns (fruit varchar(50) path '$')
       ) j
GROUP BY j.fruit;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0077c4aeee39647fed4ab0dfd5a0d06a)</kbd>

Comment: Thank. I have a question - how can I use the `JSON_EXTRACT` function if the maximum number of row elements are unknown?

Comment: @Arjun you're welcome. Indeed I advised JSON_TABLE because of this problem :) I don't know and don't think whether a dynamic method exists for JSON_EXTRACT. But luckily you have version 8.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it without first creating a table with one row per fruit.

```
CREATE TABLE allfruits (fruit VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO allfruits VALUES ('apple'), ('orange'), ('mango'), ('strawberry');
```

There is not a good way to generate this from the JSON.

Once you have that table, you can join it to the JSON and then use GROUP BY to count the occurrences.

```
SELECT fruit, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM allfruits
JOIN person ON JSON_SEARCH(person.fruits, 'one', fruit) IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY fruit;
```

Output:

```
+------------+-------+
| fruit      | count |
+------------+-------+
| apple      |     3 |
| mango      |     2 |
| orange     |     1 |
| strawberry |     1 |
+------------+-------+
```

Note that it will do a table-scan on the person table to find each fruit. This is pretty inefficient, and as your person table gets larger, it will become a performance problem.

If you want to optimize for this type of query, then you shouldn't use JSON to store an array of fruits. You should store data in a normalized way, representing the many-to-many relationship between persons and fruits with another table.

This is related to my answer to [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand your point about normalization and avoiding JSON for such a use-case. However, I am working with data where the majority can be well-fed into a relational database but there are some crucial fields in JSON.

Answer (score 1):

I think the simplest solution would be to use `JSON_TABLE` function.

The query you need is

```sql
select ft.fruit, count(ft.fruit) from person,
json_table(
  fruits,
  '$[*]' columns(
     fruit varchar(128) path '$'
    ) 
  ) as ft
  group by ft.fruit
  ;
```

You can find working example in this dbfiddle
[Fruit demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4bsPYLV9tiUkpticLcSECr/0)